# How to receive the returned result of window service if the window service has started programmatically from web service

Tags: web-services, wcf, windows-services

I have window service within a web service. I started the window service from the web service programmatically. My problem is how to receive the result of that window service in web service.code for starting the window service is

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
        ServiceController service = null;
        foreach (ServiceController Item in services)
        {
            if (Item.DisplayName == "Service1")
            {
                service = new ServiceController("Service1");
                TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);

                service.Start();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
                break;
            }
        }
```

This service will call function Execute() and that will return a string after execution.How Can i receive that string in web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

You can't.

**Long answer**

The windows services started in this manner are running in app domains which are completely isolated from the one the web service is running in. They are also isolated from each other.

In order to know the internal state of these windows services, you either need to have them implement some kind of remoting mechanism (like a web service) or have the service write to some physical resource such as a file or database.